# Is there a way to export all roles and permissions from testing environment to be imported/deployed on production environment?

Tags: 7, users, deployment

I have testing and production environments that host drupal-7. I have some roles and permissions settled on the testing environment. Can I export these roles and permissions to the production environment to avoid double effort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out these modules [Export Roles & Permissions](https://drupal.org/project/export_roles_permissions) or [Features Roles & Permission](https://drupal.org/project/features_roles_permissions)